# HTML Email can't load custom fonts from the web

Tags: html, css, webfonts

I've uploaded my custom font online.
I would like to use it to my custom HTML email using CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: FontName;
  src: url(https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cala-del-forte.appspot.com/o/web-fonts%2Ftheartisan.otf?alt=media&token=2cbbcef9-200d-49bc-8351-246c41eca80d) 
  format(otf);
}
```

But when I try to load it:

```
#fontName {

font-family: FontName;
font-size: 32px;
color: #ffffff;

}
```

and use it

```
<span id="fontName">Test</span><br>
```

It doesn't get the font from the web. It works only using local fonts (but in order to send the email I can't have other files than the index.html).

Comment: I going to call missing research efford on this one. A quick google search should have told you easily, that custom fonts for emails are only supported by a very low ammount of different email clients. There is currently no way to make them work for all email clients.

Comment: Actually I’m testing with an iMac on Google Chrome and I can’t see the custom fonts neither.

Comment: Please use the link provided. You need to use `@import`